# Display Data in Table Format with Gridlines And Suppress Columns using Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

(I’m re-posting this question to see if there is any current/additional information, or if the old information still stands; so this might be somewhat of a duplicate post because I’m looking for updated information.)

I am working with the (free) Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0, Crystal Reports Version 11 with Visual Studio 2013.  I would like to display my data in a table format, with gridlines, where I can conditionally suppress various columns.  I know how to add lines and borders to make the display/field objects  "look like a table", but conditionally suppressing a field object still leaves a space/gap between columns.  If I use Microsoft’s Report Viewer I can add a Tablix object which allows me to add gridlines and conditionally hide columns (and rows) without leaving the blank space holder.  Is there a way to do this in CR?

I have not found a way to make Cross-Tabs work for me (as some postings have suggested), as I do not need totals, I just want to list the rows in my DataTable, and again I need to conditionally suppress columns.

(I have also noticed that with Crystal Reports I am unable to add subreports to subreports, but with Microsoft Reports I can nest subreports.)

This (option 2) is an interesting way to suppress "columns", but certainly not preferred.
[[hide columns in crystal report at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445829/hide-columns-in-crystal-report-at-run-time?rq=1][1])

I haven’t found any recent posts that discuss this table issue, so I’m posting the question again in case something has changed in the last few years.

Old Posts:

[Creating tables within Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165795/creating-tables-within-crystal-reports)

[How to display grid of data in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913277/how-to-display-grid-of-data-in-crystal-reports)
[Creating a table in Crystal Reports Basic(one built in vs2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316249/creating-a-table-in-crystal-reports-basicone-built-in-vs2008)

[hide columns in crystal report at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445829/hide-columns-in-crystal-report-at-run-time?rq=1)

I don’t know if a higher version (non-free) of Crystal Reports has the table functionality that I’m wanting, or if I just need to switch to Microsoft reports.

I would appreciate your feedback.  Thank you!

Comment: what is the logic  that a column should get supressed? I mean based on what criteria you are supressing

Comment: I am suppressing columns based upon what the User wants to see.  I already have a way to obtain User input and create the necessary suppression formula.

Comment: It looks like this question is the same as one asked in June 2014, which was never answered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035250/how-to-add-table-in-crystal-report-designing-like-rdlc?rq=1